# ShieldUI filtering when using remote data

Tags: gridview, grid, shieldui

The documentation is kind of sparse on using certain functionality on the ShieldUI datasource controls as far as filtering is concerned.

I have a handler for the input, just like in the demo, but it only filters the page that is loaded and does not filter any pages that may be loaded.

How do you filter the entire dataset that could possibly loaded from the remote datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Shield UI DataSource operation (like filtering, grouping, skip, etc) can be performed either on the client side (the default) or on the server.

If you are using remote data binding and want to filter the results on the server side, you should that via the [remote.operations](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/datasource/javascript/api/settings/remote/operations) setting.

For a live example you can see [this demo](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-databinding/remote-data), but note that it contains an example how to perform "sort", "skip" and "take" operations on the server.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to pass the sort and filter values to my MVC method.

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-editing/editing-odata - you must override the remote.read.data function and pass any filtering parameters as its return value.

Comment: Seeing as you guys never post any of your server code, it is difficult to determine what is actually being passed to the remote function. That is what I'm asking.

Comment: I think the client-side code is not dependent on the server-side code - you can configure it to send whatever you want to the server... And you can use tools like Firebug for FF or IE Development Toolbar, to inspect the requests sent to the server

Comment: You can't inspect the server side code. I see that the dataObject being passed in the read but it isn't coming over to my server side code correctly.